# Deserializing a serialized Map

Tags: java, serialization

As result of applying some API method I have serialized object:

```
Serializable obj_map
```

This `obj_map` is serialized `HashMap<String, String>`. How I can convert and read this `HashMap<String, String>` from this `Serializable obj_map`?

I looked at samples with serialization/deserialization - all of them using `ObjectInputStream` and reading serialized object from file by `FileInputStream`, which is not my case. I have Serializable object as result of calling API.

Comment: You might be able to just cast it, but really we can have no idea because you haven’t told us where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

> I have Serializable object as result of calling API.

Serialization creates a file (or writes to an OutputStream). If you already have an object, you can cast it:

```
HashMap<String, String> my_map = (HashMap<String, String>) obj_map;
```

Comment: The diamond operator can’t be used like that.